# Grouping filters in Propel

Tags: php, symfony, propel

I currently have a Propel based query that looks like this:

```
$product = ProductQuery::create()
  ->filterByLive(1)
  ->filterByApproved(1)
  ->findOneByFilename($filename);
```

I regularly use this query and instead of having to chain the two filters I wondered whether it's possible to create a new filter that encapsulates them? This means that if I were to add an additional filter in future then I could simply do it in this single method rather than having to go through the entire project adding the new filter.

For example:

```
$product = ProductQuery::create()
  ->filterByIsActive()
  ->findOneByFilename($filename);
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create needed method in your `ProductQuery`:

```
public function filterByIsActive()
{
    return $this
            ->filterByLive(1)
            ->filterByApproved(1);
}
```

Propel generates this file only once and you can put any code you like inside this class - and it will not be overwritten.

Comment: Perfect, thank you! I've just found the documentation here for anyone interested: http://propelorm.org/reference/model-criteria.html#writing_your_own_business_logic_into_a_query